# how to calculate the blocking probability of processes with gamma-distributed service times using the Erlang formula?

Tags: probability, network

I have seen numerous examples of using the Erlang  formula to calculate the blocking probability for processes with exponential service times. However, I am not quite sure how to do that for a distribution which is not exponential, e.g. gamma.

Comment: What do you call the blocking probability of a process?